# passing arguments to a dynamic form in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Dynamic Form in forms. How can I pass an argument from my view when I instantiate my form?

Something like:

```
form = DynamicForm("some string argument I'm passing to my form")
```

This is the form I have:

```
class DynamicForm(Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for item in range(5):
        self.fields['test_field_%d' % item] = CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add it as keyword argument, say it's called my_arg. Make sure to `pop()` the keyword arg before calling `super()`, because the parent class's init method doesn't accept extra keyword arguments.

```
class DynamicForm(Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
    super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for item in range(5):
        self.fields['test_field_%d' % item] = CharField(max_length=255)
```

And when you create form it's like this:

```
form = DynamicForm(..., my_arg='value')
```

Comment: Just for a note, when learning about `**kwargs` .. I was always getting error like: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'my_arg'`. U have to `.pop` your arguments in first line of your constructor or at least that helped me resolve my problems.

Comment: I want to be able to inherit DynamicForm so I have a base Form class which I can pass custom parameters.  Can you show an example?

Comment: @krizajB actually, you have to kwargs.pop before super(), otherwise the base class will be receiving arguments that it doesnt support. But it doesnt have to be the *first* line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by overriding the `get_form_kwargs` of the FormMixin, available in class based views.

```
class CustomDynamicFormView(FormView):  # inherit any view with formmixin...
      form_class = DynamicForm
      
      def get_form_kwargs(self):
          kwargs = super(CustomDynamicFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
          kwargs['custom_variable'] = 'my custom variable'
          return kwargs
```

Then in your form

```
class DynamicForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_var = kwargs.pop('custom_variable') 
        # remove this b4 calling super otherwise it will complian
        super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do what you want with my_var
```

[For more information check here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/)