# Django: Using textarea widget with javascript character counter/limiter?

Tags: javascript, django, forms, textarea, widget

I am trying to use a textarea form entry which I have some javascript code to count and limit the character count, whose max_length and size are dynamic (ie these attributes are alterable after model creation).

In order to include this functionality in the django form textarea widget I suppose I would have to create a custom widget, although im not sure how to tie in the javascript code in the template really.  For changing the textarea size, i suppose I would pass a variable into the form creation from the view to generate the textarea widget instance.

Otherwise for now I am simply creating the inputs in the template in html/js and then submitting the POST data to the django view, and retrieving it using **getitem**, then saving the data directly to my models. Which works of course, but is not very django'y, and perhaps is somehow vulnerable without the built-in django validation and clean data functions.

So two questions I guess:   **(a)**  If I create a custom django form widget, how do I apply my javascript function to the textarea fields in the template (includes "onkeypress=jstextcounter...")  and **(b)** If I continue just retrieving the post data in the view without a django form, is there a vulnerability and what should I do to ensure the data is well-validated?  (page already requires user login, not a public comment box)

Or maybe someone has created such a custom form widget before and knows a good snippet somewhere?

Cheers...

**EDIT**
So thanks to MovieYoda's help, I got this working and some reading over [dynamic forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237064/passing-arguments-to-a-dynamic-form-in-django) in django.  And with a %d substitute I can dynamically change the maxChars attribute for my js function.

In forms.py I have:

```
text=forms.CharField(max_length = 1000, widget=forms.widgets.Textarea())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     size = kwargs.pop('size')
     maxChars = kwargs.pop('maxChars') 
     super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['onkeypress'] = 'return textCounter(this, this.form.counter, %d);' % maxChars
     self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['rows'] = size
     self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['cols'] = '40'
```

Where the js function 'textCounter' in the template is limiting the number of characters, using the maxChars variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function textCounter( field, countfield, maxLimit) {
  if ( field.value.length > maxLimit )
  {
    field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxLimit );
    return false;
  }
  else
  { 
    countfield.value = maxLimit - field.value.length;
  }
}
</script>
```

And in the view create the form with the kwargs inputs:

```
FormInstance = MyForm(size=1, maxChars=5)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **(a) If I create a custom django form widget, how do I apply my javascript
>   function to the textarea fields in the
>   template (includes
>   "onkeypress=jstextcounter...") and**

From what I was able to understand you want to define javascript handlers on your form elements? Here's how one can approach this -

In forms.py

```
class Search(forms.Form):
 se=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onClick':'return jscode();'}))
```

Now render your form as usual. In your js file, write this handler function jscode() & make it do what you want.

> **(b) If I continue just retrieving the post data in the view without a
>   django form, is there a vulnerability
>   and what should I do to ensure the
>   data is well-validated?**

The second part can also be easily handled. In your forms.py file define these member functions for which you want to do some data-validation. You can do it like this -

```
class Search(forms.Form):
 se=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onClick':'return jscode();'}))
 def clean_se(self):
    #do your validaton here. In case of error raise ValidationError.
    raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
```

Note that the clean fn. should be in this format - `clean_<field_to_be_cleaned>`. Here it is `se`. so...

Apart from Making sure `@login_required` - which makes sure your view is accessed by a logged in user, you need to use `csrf_token` in your form templates & `urlencode` your data (if user submits some data through the form). Now you are good to go...

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery [library](http://www.codeitbetter.co.uk/widgets/character_count/) does what you're after. It shows the user how many characters they have remaining as well as limiting the input.

Download and reference the library [here](http://www.codeitbetter.co.uk/widgets/download/) and use the following code to call it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#textarea1").CharacterCount({
            charactersRemainingControlId: "remainingCount1"
        });
    });
</script>       

<textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" cols="20" rows="3" maxlength="10"></textarea>

The number of characters left is: <span id="remainingCount1">0</span>
```