# Pass parameter to Form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custom form to which I would like to pass a parameter.
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237064/passing-arguments-to-a-dynamic-form-in-django) example I came up with the following code :

```
class EpisodeCreateForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
        super(EpisodeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    my_field = forms.CharField(initial=my_arg)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception Value: name 'my_arg' is not defined
```

How can I get it to recognize the argument in the code of the form ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the initial value by referring to the form field instance in `__init__`. To get access to the form field instance in `__init__`, put this before the call to `super`:

```
self.fields['my_field'].initial=my_arg
```

And remove `initial=my_arg` from where you declare `my_field` because at that point (when class is declared) `my_arg` is not in scope.

Comment: it doesn't know the attributes fields, is that normal ? And what if I want to later use this argument in the save method of the form ?

Comment: I goofed--the call to super needs to come before `self.fields` or else it won't exist yet.

Comment: Cool, this works ! And what if I want to use this varaible in the save method of the form ?

Comment: Well I guess I can pass it in a hidden field like this. It work. ANy way thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `my_field` is initialized when the class is created, but `my_arg` is initialized when a new instance is created, far too late for `my_field` to know its value. What you can do is initialize `my_field` in `__init__` too:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
    super(EpisodeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.my_field:
        self.my_field = my_arg
```

Comment: if I replace my_arg with self.my_arg in both places it appears, then it tells me it doesn't know self..

Comment: I can't get it to intialize the field in the init method. if I declare the form field in the init method, it juste doesn't show up.

Comment: @Johanna do it after the `super(...)` function call

Answer (score 0):

This code is executed once at import time:

```
my_field = forms.CharField(initial=my_arg)
```

and this code is executed on form instance creation:

```
my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
super(EpisodeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So this won't work this way. You should set initial value for the field in your `__init__` method.

By the way, all this seems unnecessary, why don't use 'initial' keyword in a view?

Comment: How would you use the initial keyword in a view ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment, I would do this:

```
class EpisodeCreateForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
        kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})['my_field'] = self.my_arg
        super(EpisodeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        do_something(self.my_arg)
        ...
        super(EpisodeCreateForm, self).save()

    my_field = forms.CharField()
```

Passing `initial` to the superclass and letting it do the work seems cleaner to me than directly setting it on the field instance.

Comment: the value I want to put as initial comes from the view calling the form, that's why I want to pass it as a parameter. And actually I don't just want to use it as an initial value but to perform a sql query in the save method

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pop your arg before `super()` and put it in the `fields` dictionnary after `super()` :

```
class EpisodeCreateForm(forms.Form):

    my_field = forms.CharField(label='My field:')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
        super(EpisodeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_arg'].initial = my_arg
```

Then, simply call

```
form = EpisodeCreateForm (my_arg=foo)
```

As an example, say you have a table of Episodes, and you want to show the availables ones in a choices menu, and select the current episode. For that, use a `ModelChoiceField`:

```
class EpisodeCreateForm(forms.Form):

    available_episode_list = Episode.objects.filter(available=True)

    my_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='My field:',
        queryset=available_episode_list)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cur_ep = kwargs.pop('current_episode')
        super(EpisodeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['current_episode'].initial = cur_ep
```